# Launch node with root permissions

Tags: ros, root, permissions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I need to launch a specific node with root permissions. The reason is that I need to reset a USB device under specific circumstances (sometimes the device crashes and requires to be reset). Invoking the appropriate ioctl system call requires root permissions.

I'd like to launch that node through `roslaunch`. However it should be the only node to get into god mode.

The user ROS runs under is in a sudoer. Any idea on how to acheive that?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165246/launch-node-with-root-permissions/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-15**:
open a new terminal beside others, run >sudo -s ,then > roslaunch

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-15**:
But this way all nodes run as root, don't they?

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-15**:
I don't think so, you just root the current terminal session, i.e. the current node. others are still running without root.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-15**:
But I launch all my nodes with a single roslaunch call. What you supposedly mean is rosrun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be done using the roslaunch `launch-prefix` option in the [node tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node). For example, if you user has passwordless sudo enabled, you could try:

```
<node pkg="my_pkg" type="my_node" name="my_super_node" launch-prefix="sudo"/>
```

If you don't want to set up passwordless sudo, and your node doesn't change very often, you could try setting the setuid bit on it, so that it runs as root even if started by a non-root user. The only trouble with this is that you'll have to reset the permissions whenever your node changes, and it generally won't be deployable through debs, and it will only work for compiled nodes; not for scripts.

```
cd devel/lib/my_pkg     # cd to the directory with your node
chown root:root my_node # change ownship to root
chmod a+rx my_node      # set as executable by all
chmod u+s my_node       # set the setuid bit
```

Note that both of these methods will unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH before executing your node (it's a security feature of glibc). This means that your node will either need to be statically compiled, or you'll need to turn on RPATH during the compilation process, so that the library search path is included in your executable rather than relying on the environment to be set up correctly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-16**:
Sounds promising. Is it possible to use passwordless sudo even with a Python node? I'm okay with passwordless sudo.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-16**:
Yes, I think passwordless sudo with a python node should work. You may want to check that sudo is configured to pass the PYTHONPATH variable.

**Comment by [Wedigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23417/wedigo/) on 2015-07-31**:
I know this old question, but I got stuck on that issue for some days.

Could someone please be more specific how this is solved, especially concerning the staical compilation and turning on the RPATH?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-08-08**:
Have a look at https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

**Comment by [Wedigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23417/wedigo/) on 2015-08-10**:
Thank you for the link.

I found a solution before you posted this. I added the needed environment variables to the sudo prefix in the .launch file. It works for now....

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-20**:
if using `sudo` as the launch-prefix, it may be necessary to use `sudo -E` to preserve the ROS environment variables.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-08-02**:
hi ! how can I do the reverse of the command line 4 instructions set ? This broke my node and I don't understand the following documentation well enough to do the compilation part of the fix. Between, I'm trying to solve [this](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/issues/23)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-08-02**:
You can remove the setuid bit with `sudo chmod u-s my_node`

**Comment by [muttidrhummer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32095/muttidrhummer/) on 2019-01-18**:
i noticed that when i close the launchfile in which i ran some nodes with sudo , the sudo nodes won't close at at all, any idea?